# Logout button doesn't work in razor - it doesn't go to Identity/Account/LogOut

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When I click on the logout button in the razor component LoginDisplay.razor, it navigates but it doesn't come over to the Logout.cshtml.cs in the MyApplication.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
{
   .... // doesn't come over here
}
```

startup.cs

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
```

LoginDisplay.razor

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
    <form method="post" action="Identity/Account/LogOut">
        <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log out</button>
    </form>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
    <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>
</NotAuthorized>
```

When I click on the log out button, the output is:

[image]

Comment: While seeing the HTTP Error 400 screen, does it work when you refresh the page? I remember I had this issue once.  Worst case, it can then be resolved by using NavigationManager instead: navigator.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/LogOut", true);

Comment: @DaniëlHoffman No, it doesn't work even when refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I fixed it by added the `@attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` to the header of my `/Identity/Account/Logout.cshtml` file (right above the @model).

I still can't explain precisely why it works from any `/Identity/*` page and it would return a 400 error from my Blazor Server App. Although, I played with the generated HTML in my browser, and noticed a missing forgery field on my Blazor-generated page. All my forms were identical, but for some reason the field wasn't generated by the server. At some point, I decided to manually add the missing field to my form (from within the browser), and the submit form did in fact log me out.

Tl;dr:

```
@page
@attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] // <-- insert this line
@model LogoutModel
...
// Your Logout page :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to revert to the original LogOut.cshtml version - without any LogOut.cshtml.cs, to see if there's a problem in your customised LogOut page.

My entire LogOut.cshtml looks like follows, and works with your exact code:

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager //Could be IdentityUser instead of ApplicationUser
@functions {
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
        {
            await SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
        }

        return Redirect("~/Identity/Account/Login");
    }
}
```